# How to remove same value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array. I want to duplicate all records form an array. I tried `array_unique` but it's removing duplicate but doesn't remove orignal value.

```
Array   (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 6
        [5] => 1
        [6] => 23
        [7] => 2
)
```

I want to remove all duplicate value like 1 and 2 and I want this output :

```
Array
(
        [0] => 3
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 23

)
```

Comment: @Mohammad not actually.

Comment: if you are getting this from the DB, I bet you can use a query itself to achieve it, otherwise it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
$values = [1,2,3,1,6,1,23,2];
$result = array_filter(array_count_values($values), function($x) {
    return $x === 1;
});

print_r(array_keys($result));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 23
)
```

Comment: just add `print_r(array_keys($result))`

Comment: This needs to be `array_keys($result)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use array_intersect with array_count_values.
Array_intersect returns values that is 1, and array_keys returns the keys (values).

```
$values = [1,2,3,1,6,1,23,2];

$result = array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values($values), [1]));

var_dump($result); //[3,6,23]
```

https://3v4l.org/cHU5E

---

Another option is to use array_unique and the use array_diff_assoc() to get a list of what has been removed.
Using that array list in array_diff results in the values that is not duplicated.

```
$values = [1,2,3,1,6,1,23,2];
$diff = array_diff_assoc($values, array_unique($values));
$result = array_diff($values, $diff);
var_dump($result); //[3,6,23]
```

https://3v4l.org/XM5sk